# Listing all Collections in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm building a magazine site with Jekyll (v2.5.3). The docs on [the Jekyll site](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) led me to believe that I could list all the collections on my site, and embed YAML data for each collection in my `_config.yml`.

_config.yml:

```
collections:
  issue_001:
    output: true
    permalink: /:title/:path
    title: Rebirth
    date: 2015-07-01
  issue_002:
    output: true
    permalink: /:title/:path
    title: Talking Heads
    date: 2015-08-01
```

index.html:

```
{% for issue in site.collections %}
  <li>
    <h6 class="post-meta">Issue {{ issue.name }} &mdash; {{ issue.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</h6>

    <h2>
      {{ issue.title }}
    </h2>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I get two issues appearing on the homepage, but none of the data I'm accessing for each issue (name, date, title etc.) is appearing. I appreciate this is a beta feature, so just wanted to ask is this broken, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `{% for issue in site.collections %}`, `issue` is an array that contains :

```
0 => "issue_001",
1 => Hash
 {"output"=>true,
  "permalink"=>"/:title/:path",
  "title"=>"Rebirth",
  "date"=>#,
  "label"=>"issue_001",
  "docs"=>[#],
  "files"=>[],
  "directory"=>"/home/djacquel/www/test.dev/jekyll/wat/_issue_001",
  "relative_directory"=>"_issue_001"}
```

The right way to access datas is :

```
{% for issue in site.collections %}
  <li>
    <h6 class="post-meta">
      Issue {{ issue[1].label }}
      &mdash;
      {{ issue[1].date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}
    </h6>
    <h2>
      {{ issue[1].title }}
    </h2>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Liquid Exception: 1 is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: @Edward, you can post a question describing your problem with datas and code. A simple error message is not enough.

Comment: If you scroll just above my comment, I used your solution but I received that error. I'm  using jekyll 3.8.4

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/52219979/3411192

Answer (score 16):

In case for someone still has this request here's how it works in latest Jekyll (v3.8.3):

Update: tested it still works in v4.2.0

```html
{% for collection in site.collections %}
  <h2>Items from {{ collection.label }}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for item in site[collection.label] %}
      <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: suppose i wanted to skip the first for loop an access a specific collection at _notes, how would I access/list the items that way?

Answer (score 4):

Second first; that [answer from @sparanoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52219979/2632107) is fantastic! And between that and the source code from the default Jekyll Theme (Minima), I was able to bodge some of what follows together.

First second; excellent question and how both are not up-voted more is a bit baffling.

And third of many other related points; I'm not on a identical path as the question's poster but the following code may be of use to readers. My use case was wanting a way of listing the continence of a collection similar to the default Jekyll `home` layout.

#### [`_layouts/named_collection.html`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/blob/01f2fb21a681b376b5c685643f19a7d290873944/_layouts/named_collection.html)

> Note the source links are downloadable via, clicking on the `Raw` link/button then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> to save as a regular text file, however, these links have been *frozen in time* so be sure to check the [`gh-pages`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/tree/gh-pages) branch for updates. And output examples are intended in this case to be just examples of possible content, eg. it could be *Lorem strings* for all that it matters to demonstrate what's to follow.

```html
---
layout: default
---
{% comment %}
License note from S0AndS0; an editor in this context.

Minima (where the following code is sourced from), is shared under the
 MIT Lisense, https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Thus any alterations to Minima source code is re-shared under the MIT Lisense
{% endcomment %}
{% capture workspace_collections %}
  {% assign collection_name = page.collection_name | default: include.collection_name | default: nil %}
  {% assign target_collection = site[collection_name] %}

  <div class="home">
    {%- if page.title -%}
      <h1 class="page-heading">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {%- endif -%}

    {{ content }}

    {% assign has_output = False %}
    {%- if target_collection.size > 0 -%}
      {% capture workspace_collection %}
        <h2 class="post-list-heading">{{ page.list_title | default: "Posts" }}</h2>
        <ul class="post-list">
          {%- for post in target_collection -%}
            {%- if page.relative_path == post.relative_path -%}
              {%- continue -%}
            {%- else -%}
              {% assign has_output = True %}
            {%- endif -%}

            <li>
              {%- assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%b %-d, %Y" -%}
              <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: date_format }}</span>
              <h3>
                <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
                  {{ post.title | escape }}
                </a>
              </h3>
              {%- if site.show_excerpts -%}
                {{ post.excerpt | markdownify | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}
              {%- endif -%}
            </li>
          {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
      {% endcapture %}

      {%- if has_output == True -%}
        {{- workspace_collection -}}{% assign workspace_collection = nil %}
      {%- endif -%}

    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
{% endcapture %}{{ workspace_collections | strip }}{% assign workspace_collections = nil %}
```

> Side note, I can't remember where I picked up that `capture` some `workspace_` trick, but it's pretty sweat for *`strip`ping new* lines and other formatting shenanigans. If a reader figures out who started such fanciness, please edit or leave a comment.

---

Usage of this layout is much like the usage of Minima's [`home.html`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_layouts/home.html) layout.

#### [`administration.md`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/blob/72701296fcace1a0b85eb0aa2c7bcc2daf634203/administration.md)

... Front-Matter selecting from the [`_administration`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/tree/gh-pages/_administration) collection looks like...

```yaml
layout: named_collection
collection_name: administration
title: Administration
list_title: Usage Examples
permalink: /admin/
```

... resulting in a [`<base-url>/admin/`](https://s0ands0.github.io/Jekyll_Admin/admin/) collection listing being output.

#### [`git_shell_commands.md`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/blob/72701296fcace1a0b85eb0aa2c7bcc2daf634203/git_shell_commands.md)

... Front-Matter selecting from the [`_git_shell_commands`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/tree/gh-pages/_git_shell_commands) collection looks like...

```yaml
layout: named_collection
collection_name: git_shell_commands
title: Git Shell Commands
list_title: Usage Examples
permalink: /git_shell_commands/
```

... resulting in a [`<base-url>/git_shell_commands/`](https://s0ands0.github.io/Jekyll_Admin/git_shell_commands/) collection listing being output.

---

### Even more notes on collections

If I'm reading the latest [Jekyll Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) documentation correctly, as of version `3.7.0` it could be possible to have a custom collections directory, in the case of this question that might look like...

```sh
ls ~/git/magazine-name/
# ... other files and/or directories
#   issues/
# ... other files and/or directories
#   _config.yml
```

... where the `issues/` directory contains sub-directories such as...

```sh
ls ~/git/magazine-name/issues/
#   _001/
#   _002/
#   _003/
# ...
```

... and the `_config.yml` file has...

```yaml
collections_dir: issues
collections:
  001:
    output: True
    # ...
```

... the *magic sauce* was `collections_dir` and **not** using an under-scored prefixed base directory. The documentation was *loud* about that last bit, eg. `_issues/` would make for a *bad time*.

I'm not sure if there'd be any other adjustments needed to the previously posted Liquid code (I don't think so, but probably); so maybe try'em out individually first.

> ### Warning/Update
>
> Jekyll does **not** take kindly to numbered collections, eg. `_000` **will** cause errors!
>   To mitigate such issues be sure to trick Jekyll into treating collection names as strings, eg. `_i000`

The reason I suggest using a `collections_dir`, is because in the case of [@James Dinsdale's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31171041/2632107) it may help in organizing things a bit more. Personally I wanted my `gh-pages` branch collection to *mirror* some of the same paths as my project's `master` branch, so didn't pursue testing `collections_dir` suggestions.

---

### Notes about my Liquid coding choices

Because I'm using the Minima theme I placed the files that used the `named_collection` theme in my project's root directory; default behavior is to link to such *`pages`* at the top of every page. Cheap navigation.

Because readers might place pages that use the `named_collection` within the same directory as what is being listed, eg...

```sh
ls Jekyll_Admin/_administration/
#   _administration/administration.md
# ...
```

... I've written the Liquid for some of the edge-cases, but may not have covered all of'em. Be sure to test privately before unleashing something like it on production.

---

### Updates

After some testing with `collections_dir` it looks like when used the `_posts` directory **must** be moved to that directory too, eg...

**[`_config.yml`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/S0AndS0.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml) (Snip)**

```
collections_dir: misc
```

**Bash commands**

```
mkdir misc
mv _posts misc/
```

... though that's only applicable if using a `_posts` directory.

---

Between the time of the last edit and when you're now reading this I've published [`liquid-utilities/collection-home`](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/collection-home) on GitHub; might be of use to those that want a version tracked solution and is what I'm currently using in any projects that require this feature.