# Jekyll: Sort items in collections, while looping over collections

Tags: jekyll

I want to loop over all of the collections in my Jekyll site, and within that I want to sort and list all of the pages in that collection.

[Based on this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52219979/2552873), I can loop through all the collections and items:

```html
{% for collection in site.collections %}
  <h2>Items from {{ collection.label }}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% assign pages = site[collection.label] %}
    {% for item in pages %}
      <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

For a specific collection, I can also sort the update field from the frontmatter:

```
{% assign sorted = site.programming | sort: 'update' %}
```

But if I try to apply this to the 1st example, it fails:

```
{% assign pages = site[collection.label] | sort: 'update' %}
```

This gives a rather generically useless error:

```
  Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 30): comparison of Array with Array failed in index.md
             Error: Liquid error (line 30): comparison of Array with Array failed
             Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

I'm guessing that somehow `site[collection.label]` returns something different than `site.programming`, but I'm not sure what, or how to solve this.

EDIT: I tried using `collection.docs` instead of `site[collection.label]` and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this error turned out not to be the difference between `collection.docs` and `site[collection.label]`. Rather, in one of the collections, there was an item where the frontmatter did not contain the `update` field. As a result, it couldn't sort by this field because not all items had it. Similarly, you get the same error if the *types* are not comparable in all cases. In this case, they were all supposed to be dates; if one was not a valid date format, it failed.

I still think this is a terribly ambiguous error message.